# Root route error on server LARAVEL ! ( www.servername.com'/' )

Tags: laravel

when I go on my server, if the url is empty nothing is displayed ...
However I tested a lot of things with my roads and it works perfectly locally.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/welcome');
});
```

```
Route::get('/', function () { return redirect()->route('home', substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2)); });

Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}'], function () {
   Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home'); 
});
```

Comment: Where you want to redirect, `home` is your view or route name?

Comment: Can I see the code, where you define the `home`?

Comment: @STA sorry redirect to ('/welcome')

Comment: Use name route for welcome `return redirect()->route('welcome');`

Comment: @STA Yes this syntax works locally but not on the servers !

Comment: Which error did you get on live server? Show me all your route

Comment: Show me your route code, from `…/routes/web.php`

Comment: Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect()->route('home', substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2));
});

Comment: @STA Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}'], function () {Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home'); });

Comment: removed the [tag:apache] and [tag:nginx] tags. If you add one of them again, explain how the server is relevant in your question. As you tagged both: the odds that they both are relevant is quite low.

Comment: @OlafKock Bbecause my routing works locally but not in production on an apache or nginx server.

Comment: Please see [ask] and add information to your question. "I've tried a lot of things" is not reproducible, and the only thing anyone can say based on that is "you'll need to try _something else_", which, admittedly, is not very helpful.